# Xml Serialization of ReadOnlyCollections

Tags: c#

I have some container classes that expose their collections through a ReadOnlyCollection. Custom Methods are provided to Add and Remove from the collection which also perform some custom logic.

For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    List<Bar> _barList = new List<Bar>();

    public ReadOnlyCollection<Bar> BarList
    {
        get { return _barList.AsReadOnly(); }
    }

    public void AddBar(Bar bar)
    {
        if (bar.Value > 10)
            _barList.Add(bar);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot add to Foo. The value of Bar is too high");
    }
    public void RemoveBar(Bar bar)
    {
        _barList.Remove(bar);
        // Foo.DoSomeOtherStuff();
    }

}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is all well and good but when i come to serialise Foo with the Xml Serializer an exception is thrown.

Can anyone offer a good way of going about this?

Thanks

Comment: It throws a InvalidOperationException due to an error in reflecting Foo.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, that won't work. So don't do that. Additionally, there are no hooks to detect xml serialization except the oh-so-painful `IXmlSerializable`.

So either:

- don't use a read-only collection here
- implement `IXmlSerializable` (tricky)
- have a dual API (one read-only, one not; serialize the "not" - tricky as `XmlSerializer` only handles publicx members)
- use a separate DTO for serialization

Answer (score 2):

You can't deserialize `ReadOnlyCollection` because it does not has `Add` method.
To fix that use a second property for serialization:

```
[XmlIgnore()]
public ReadOnlyCollection<Bar> BarList
{
    get { return _barList.AsReadOnly(); }
}

[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
//[Obsolete("This is only for serialization process", true)]
[XmlArray("BarList")]
[XmlArrayItem("Bar")]
public List<Bar> XmlBarList
{
    get { return _barList; }
    set { _barList = value; }
}
```

Comment: @Frederik: Just give it a test and found out you are right. the `Obsolete` properties will not serialized. Thanks for the comment and sorry for my _insistence_ that it does..

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, i'm also finding adding the Obsolete tag prevents the serialisation

Comment: @Cadair: Did you find any of these answers useful? What did you use?

Comment: @Jalal, I've not got where i wanted really. Thanks for your suggestions though. thing is I didn't want to expose a public List<> since this allows objects to be added directly to the list bypassing my custom Add() and Remove() methods. This seems to be the only way as far as the xml serialisation is concerned, i'll have to rethink

Answer (score 0):

XML Serialization only serializes **properties** that have a getter and a setter.
You can use the [SoapFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter.aspx), [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) or  [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx).